# Magnitude of projection proof

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I don't get how the magnitude of projection formula follows from the projection vector.

$proj_v(u) = \frac{u \cdot v}{|v|} \frac{v}{|v|}$

$|proj_v(u)| = \frac{|u \cdot v|}{|v|}$

Comment: Well, what is the length of vector $\frac v{|v|}$? By the way, an absolute value sign is missing from the denominator as $u\cdot v$ can be negative as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your magnitude is incorrect since the [magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_(mathematics)) of a vector is the length of the vector, denoted as $∥a∥$ which is non-negative.
It should be $|proj_v(u)| = \frac{|u \cdot v|}{|v|}=|u\cos(u,v)|.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The norm $\lVert w \rVert$ of a vector $w$ has the property that $\lVert aw \rVert = |a|\lVert w \rVert$ for all scalars $a$.